# How to remove form elements before post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page with a javascript auto fill textbox. I am loading all the content into a hidden field and loading it to text box in jquery document.load function.

Here, my problem is when i do a response.redirect in button click to another page, my page is very slow. I enabled trace in iis and noticed that hidden field value is uploading to server. It is a huge data, I disabled viewstate for that hidden field but no use.

How to remove this hidden field from form elements list before post back. Or is there another way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery remove should do the trick for you I believe:
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Thank, that solved my problem. But is there any event fires before post back so that i can remove any form element.